# What is the difference between probabilistic graphical model and graphical model?

Tags: distributions, graphical-model

In this [note: Lecture 1: Introduction to Graphical Models](https://sailinglab.github.io/pgm-spring-2019/notes/lecture-01/), it reads that

> Next, we will elaborate on the difference between Probabilistic
>   Graphical Models (PGM) and Graphical Models (GM). In brief, a PGM adds
>   structure to a multivariate statistical distribution, while a GM adds
>   structure to any multivariate objective function.

What are the "multivariate statistical distribution" and "multivariate objective function"? Is the probabilistic graphical model just the directed acyclic graph or Bayesian network? To quote from [this paper: Getting Started in Probabilistic Graphical Models](https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/2757496/Airoldi_GettingStarted.pdf):

> A number of scholars choose to refer to PGMs that can be represented
>   as directed acyclic graphs, with nodes corresponding to
>   discrete-valued random variables, encoding observed measurements, and
>   no latent variables as Bayesian networks.)

But in [this blog: A Gentle Introduction to Bayesian Belief Networks](https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-bayesian-belief-networks/), it states that

> A probabilistic graphical model (PGM), or simply “graphical model” for
>   short, is a way of representing a probabilistic model with a graph
>   structure.

And in this [tag description](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-model) it also writes that

> Also called Probabilistic Graphical Model, used for statistical models
>   expressed via graphs, causal or not. (Nb, "graph" as in graph theory,
>   *not* as in figure or plot).

They just use PGM's as a synonym of graphical models. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it seems that the authors in the notes are using the GMs as a general term to describe a graph structure (that could describe a model) while the PGMs are more specifically used as graphs that model theoretical (or observed?) distributions. They don't seem to be something different; the GM is the parent category.

Comment: @M.Cris If GM is the parent category what else it contains?

Comment: Go to the wikipedia page for GMs.
"Generally, probabilistic graphical models use a graph-based representation as the foundation for encoding a distribution over a multi-dimensional space and a graph that is a compact or factorized representation of a set of independences that hold in the specific distribution"
There are the "distribution encoders" and the "factorization representations".

Comment: You may also further categorize them by Bayesian directed GMs which can be in the family of chain graphs (also included in the wikipedia page), PGMs, trees etc. Unfortunately I am not eligible to enclose a full answer, rather to give some insight about the GM.